# hdfs dfs command is slow - is there a way to make it faster?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am on `Hadoop 2.2.0`, running a Single Node setup.

My understanding is that `hdfs dfs -ls` is slow because it is spinning up a `JVM` every time it is invoked.

Is there any way to make it keep the JVM running so simple commands can complete faster?

Comment: Try executing a command with logging enabled `HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER=DEBUG,console hdfs dfs -ls ~`. This might give you a clue whether your assumption about the JVM-boot-time is correct or that there might be something else happening.

Comment: Hadoop fs -ls was running very slow, taking 20 seconds to start. I figured out that when I am connected to wifi, it happens. So when I need to run hadoop commands, I disconnect wifi. not sure what is the issue, but I am happy.

Answer (score 9):

I would like to inform you about a solution we did to solve this problem.

We created a new utility - **HDFS Shell** to work with HDFS more faster.

https://github.com/avast/hdfs-shell

- HDFS DFS initiates JVM for each command call, HDFS Shell does it only once - which means great speed enhancement when you need to work with HDFS more often
- Commands can be used in short way - eg. `hdfs dfs -ls /`, `ls /` - both will work
- **HDFS path completion using TAB key**
- we can easily add any other HDFS manipulation function
- there is a command history persisting in history log (~/.hdfs-shell/hdfs-shell.log)
- **support for relative directory + commands `cd` and `pwd`**
- and much more...

Answer (score 1):

In the pig grunt shell commands like `fs -ls` work quite fast, so that might be a pragmatic workaround. The problem is that this doesn't work well when trying to pipe the output to other commands.

So I hacked a script together to start the pig grunt shell as a background process and communicate with it via named pipes: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144722/46085. The problem is that even though I use the `script` tool to fake a real terminal (because the grunt shell expects that), the grunt shell still kills itself sometimes. I also get problems when truncating the output with `head` or so, because it still tries to write the whole output which in turn can leave stale output in the named pipe.

Anyway you might have a look and see if it works for you. I appreciate any improvements you may find.

Comment: I had another look and it seems I finally found a way of redirecting which keeps the grunt shell stable: http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/144722/revisions. So what remains is a proper way to handle pipes through `head`.

Comment: Now I remember why I didn't settle for this solution in July: when outputting file content with `-text` or `-cat` it gets truncated after a few KB, for whatever reason, but I wanted the full output, which worked when doing the stdout redirect differently. `ls` works fine though (even with long listings), so I guess this is the better solution since its at least reliable.

Comment: Just being able to browse files faster on the command line is great for productivity!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Hadoop Tools](https://github.com/jystic/hadoop-tools). It provides a similar interface to `hdfs dfs` but is much faster. It also supports tab completion of filenames on HDFS with bash completion, which is a huge time saver.

It doesn't support `put` yet though.